Add new joint to ARKit skeleton
I want to add new joint in addition to joints that provided by ARKit. for example extract the position of wrist and elbow, then add new joint between them in the middle of arm.
I could extract joint position but I couldn't assign new position to joint.
I can't find a good documentation that can explain ARKit very well. If there is another information that I can use, please share it with me. thanks
